# ics VALARM support across clients

Tags: icalendar

I am wondering about the `BEGIN:VALARM` value in ics.

I have set an alarm, but Outlook (PC) and Calendar (Mac) seems to ignore the alarm altogether. In eM Client (PC) the alarm is set but cannot be dismissed (pops up again immediately after dismiss)

Is this a known problem with the iCalendar/ics standard?

The format seems to be valid. Are any additional values needed for each client to understand/accept and handle the alert correctly?

I am subscribing to the .ics file via a `https://` URL.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
PRODID:adamgibbons/ics
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-PUBLISHED-TTL:PT1H
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:-LovTg9y9HPDCHu8mVnD
SUMMARY:Purjolök
DTSTAMP:20191026T171500Z
DTSTART:20191024T080000Z
DESCRIPTION:En grönsak i lökfamiljen
URL:https://app.myapp.se/r/edit/-LovTg9y9HPDCHu8mVnD
STATUS:CONFIRMED
CATEGORIES:Matlista
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:En grönsak i lökfamiljen
TRIGGER:-PT10M
END:VALARM
DURATION:PT30M
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is most likely nothing wrong with your code and most clients will ignore those alarms by design.

Whether you receive an invitation via email or subscribe to a calendar via http, you don't want the organiser of the meeting/author of the calendar feed to dictate when/if you should be reminded. It is really up to the attendee/subscriber to set their own alarms.

If, on the other hand, you "import" the same ics file, the alarms will be taken into account (the client considers that the stream already belongs to you and that it is a "backup" of your own calendar).